# Save File with AppendText

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a richTextbox es:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

use this for save file `File.WriteAllText(name, (richTextBox1.Text));`
but the file returns this `line1lin2line3`
is possiible to save file in this way?

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that for whatever reason, `RichTextBox` is using the Unix linebreak of just `\n`. Try this:

```
File.WriteAllText(name, richTextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
```

Comment: I dunno when I use this.

string message = "line1\nline2\nline3";
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test.txt", message);

The output comes out like he wants.

Comment: @Cubicle: It depends on how you read it. Some text editors can cope with "\n", others (e.g. notepad) can't.

Answer (score 1):

For writing to file:

```
File.WriteAllLines("my file.txt", this.richTextBox1.Lines);
```

for appending:

```
File.AppendAllLines("my file.txt", this.richTextBox1.Lines);
```

Comment: also you can use the designed `SaveFile` method of the control as Marco mentioned

Answer (score 0):

What about `richTextBox1.SaveFile(file_name)`?
Or `richTextBox1.SaveFile(file_name, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the individual lines by using the 'Lines' property.

```
string[] linesintextbox = richTextBox1.Lines;
File.WriteAllLines("xyz.txt", linesintextbox);
```